# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

My route:
`Route::get('/user/{username}', [
    'uses' => '\MostWanted\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getProfile',
    'as' => 'profile.index',
]);`

My Controller:

```
namespace MostWanted\Http\Controllers;

use MostWanted\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function getProfile($username)
    {

        $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

        if (!$user) {
            abort(404);
        }

        return view('profile.index');

    }
}
```

What it views:

```
@extends('templates.default')

@section('content')


    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <!-- User information and statuses -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-3">
                <!-- Friends, friend requests -->
            </div>
        </div>

@stop
```

I'm quite sure the code is correct but it still has this error. Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: please have a look at this answer it may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53943911/5068530

Answer (score 0):

Did you make you that username exists in database ?

```
$user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
if (!$user) {
    return 'User does not exists';
}
```

Your code with abort(404) can be replaced with

```
$user = User::where('username', $username)->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Yep. username exists in the migration table.

Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) { 
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('username');
  $table->string('last_name');
  $table->string('email');
  $table->string('password');
  $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
  $table->string('location')->nullable();
  $table->string('remember_token')->nullable();
  $table->timestamps();
  });
    }

Comment: No, assume url like this : /user/admin => has username ***admin*** already exists in database ?

Comment: No. Probably not. 

I am currently using Windows 10. Is there any way I can access the database? If so, how?

Comment: I found out it exists, but it just somehow won't show up when I click the link but when I manually add the {username} in link, it shows up.